On the Admin orders , Account information and Address Information (the shipping and billing addresses) are missing in magento 2.4.6
On the Admin side, for some orders, it was noticed that order and account information and Address Information (the shipping and billing addresses) are missing.
After version upgrade from 2.4.3 to 2.4.6 , for some orders it shows properly.
Any idea guys. How to debug on it

Thanks,
